# Standard way to take multiple files as input in Java main class using docker

Tags: java, docker, maven

I am creating a Java Maven project with main class i.e. it is executable. I require multiple json files as input from user, these files could be in arbitrary amount (i.e. the number of files is not fixed).

Then I have to create a docker image of this project, how could I take these arbitrary number of json files from user and use it in the Java class using Docker.

Any help with suggestions/links would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the json files included in docker image or consume them from docker image but keeping them outside of image?

Comment: If the main goal of your process is to process files that live on the host system, you'll find Docker's core filesystem isolation features to work against you, and you might find it substantially easier to run your program directly on the host.